# Creating a project with one EXE file and remaining as DLL files

Tags: vb.net

How do I create a project with one EXE file and the remaining files as DLL files? I have 24 forms in my windows application. I am using VB.NET.

Comment: You're not asking for anything.. see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for some advice on asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

So your question is?  Assuming you know how to use Visual Studio go ahead and develop normally, you would need a new project for each physical output file you want to create (.exe or .dll).  To choose how each is compiled you right click on the project, choose properties and change output type accordingly:

- Class Library creates a DLL
- Windows Application creates an EXE

You don't mention the reasons behind doing this, if you maybe elaborate more we could probably provide more tailored advice.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to add a Class Library project to you solution and add your other files in there, this will then compile to a .dll as well as your .exe. To add the class library, right click on your solution and choose add new item, then selected class library.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other have mentioned it seems you want to add a class library to your project to make it more manageable. You don't mention if you have any experience in creating class libraries in vb.net or not so I took the liberty of hunting out a tutorial on it [here](http://vbdotnetbyexample.blogspot.co.uk/)